# Automate detection of obvious loan shark spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

We have seem a spate of loan shark spam postings. Is there a way to detect these and invite users to mark them as likely spam, promoting spam flagging over down voting?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, this is possible, and it's usually done. There is a [community-run project](https://charcoal-se.org/) that normally detects and [automatically flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/294691) spam, removing it within minutes to seconds.
However, this project (Charcoal, running the bot SmokeDetector) is currently [on strike](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) as part of a [network-wide moderation strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/294691) in protest of recent actions by Stack Exchange, Inc.

If you'd like this project to get back up and running, you can help us by putting pressure on the company to give in to the strike's [demands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/294691) and help resolve this issue faster.

Comment: Didn't know about the mod strike. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

> invite users to mark them as likely spam, promoting spam flagging over down voting?

We already do that. [These](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22don%27t%20downvote%20spam%22&searchOn=3) [lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22flag%20spam%22&searchOn=3) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22close%20spam%22&searchOn=3) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22downvote%20spam%22) [show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22spam%20review%22&searchOn=3) [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22flagging%20spam%22&searchOn=3) [clearly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22downvoting%20spam%22). Unless you want a popup? And yes I agree with the other answer about Charcoal, no need to restate here. Note that metasmoke's also not flagging new things though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I should have thought to search on meta before posting my question! As to the strike, I'm on the side of banning AI posts for all the reasons cited in the background shared in the other answer. Shame the automation is not operating during the strike.